# VSCode auto format without line wrap

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Is there any extension or settings in VSCode where I can apply auto format but the line should not break to multi line.

Tried prettier but it breaks my conditions, statements or the function headers into multi lines.

[image]

Comment: This is probably due to the `"prettier.printWidth"` property.
The default is 80, you can try 120, should solve your problem.

Answer (score 15):

this is late but may be it helps someone else. All you have to do is go to

-> **settings** -> search "**wrap**"

-> **Word Wrap** -> mark this "**off**"

-> **Word Wrap Column** -> give this any number greater then 80(which is default)

-> **Wrapping Intend** -> Make this "**none**"

-> **Debug > Console: Word Wrap** -> **Uncheck it**

-> **HTML > Format: Wrap Line Length** -> Change it to "**0**"

-> Edit "**Settings.json**" file and add following at end:

```
"[markdown]": {
  
    "editor.wordWrap": "off",
    "editor.quickSuggestions": true
},
```

-> Restart VS Code and now line wrapping issue is fixed

Comment: Note that setting **HTML > Format: Wrap Line Length** to 0 is the only one needed to disable the wrapping when auto formatting.